# Limit distribution of the number of longest runs in a random binary sequence of length $n\to\infty.$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Let $X_n$ be the **number of longest runs** in a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli(1/2) random variables. Here, "run" means a nonempty block of adjacent $1$s; e.g., in the sequence $110110001$, there are two longest runs (each being $11$).

By using a program from OEIS, the limiting distribution of $X_n$, as $n\to\infty,$ is "empirically" suggested to be
$$p_k:=\lim_{n\to\infty}P[X_n=k]={1\over k\ 2^k\ \log(2)}\ \ (k=1,2,3,...)$$

**Question**: As this is probably a known result, can someone cite a published proof? (Or provide any information on how to prove it.)

"Derivation":
As described [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/206950/16397), for $n\ge 1$, there is a bijection between (a) the [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))  of $n$ with exactly $k$  largest parts, and (b) the binary strings of length $n-1$ with exactly $k$ longest runs of $1$s, such that these are equal in number. This number is listed as $T(n,k)$ at [OEIS A238341](https://oeis.org/A238341), where a  program for $T(n,k)$ is also given. (I've [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845418/algorithm-for-the-number-of-compositions-of-n-with-exactly-k-occurrences-of) a separate question asking for explanation/sources of the algorithm implemented by this program.)

**NB**: Letting $A(n,k)$ be the number of length-$n$ binary strings with $k$ longest runs, and $T(n,k)$ be the number of compositions of $n$ with exactly $k$  largest parts, there is an "edge effect" due to which these are related as follows:

$$A(n,k)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $k=0$}\\[1ex]
T(n+1,k) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and it is to be noted that in fact $A(n,k)=0$ if $k\gt\lceil{n\over 2}\rceil$.

Thus, we have
$$P[X_n=k]={A(n,k)\over 2^n} \ \ (k=0,1,2,3,...)$$

Using the OEIS program gives $P[X_n=1]\approx 0.7213$ for $n\gt 100,$ which led me to guess that $p_1={1\over 2 \log 2}$. I then let $c_k:= p_k\ \log 2$, which implies $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k=\log 2;$  i.e.,  a series converging to $\log 2.$  One of the best-known such series is $c_k={1\over k\ 2^k},$  which is strongly supported by computing $(P[X_n=k] \log 2)_{n\gt 100}\approx(1/2,1/8,1/24,1/64, 1/160,...)=({1\over k\ 2^k})_{k=1,2,...}.$

---

A Python/SageMath rendition of the OEIS program is online at [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=ctrrqf). It takes about a minute there to plot $(P[X_n=k])_{n=1..45}$ for $k=0,1,2,3$.

---

**Aside**:
(Sorry for the length, but I thought someone might be interested ...)

@kodlu's comment has led me to show that the **limit distribution of the number of longest runs** in a random binary sequence of length $n\to\infty$ *is the same distribution for all of the following different definitions of "run"*:

- D1:  "run" means a nonempty block of adjacent $1$s.
- D2:  "run" means a nonempty block of adjacent $1$s, **or** a nonempty block of adjacent $0$s.
- D3:  "run" means a nonempty block of adjacent $1$s, flanked on each side either by a $0$ or by the start/end of the sequence.
- D4:   "run" means a nonempty block of adjacent $1$s, flanked on each side either by a $0$ or by the start/end of the sequence, **or** a nonempty block of adjacent $0$s, flanked on each side either by a $1$ or by the start/end of the sequence.

Proof:

Clearly, D1 and D3 give the same distribution for all $n$ because the *longest* run is the same by either definition (hence the limit distributions are the same). Similarly, D2 and D4 give the same distribution for all $n$ (though different from  those for D1 and D3).

Therefore, all that remains to show is that the *limit* distribution for D1 is the same as that for D2. To do so, let $A(n,k)$ (resp. $B(n,k)$) denote the number of length-$n$ binary strings with exactly $k$ longest runs,  according to definition D1 (resp. D2), and let $X_n(s)$ (resp. $Y_n(s)$) denote the number of longest runs in sequence $s$, according to definition D1 (D2, resp.).  We will show that $$B(n,k)=2\ A(n-1,k)  \ \ (0\lt k\lt n)$$
from which it follows that for $0\lt k\lt n$,
$$P[Y_n=k] = {B(n,k)\over 2^n}={A(n-1,k)\over 2^{n-1}}=P[X_{n-1}=k]
$$
and hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P[Y_n=k]=\lim_{n\to\infty}P[X_n=k]\ \ (k=1,2,3,\dots).$$

(We can dispense with $k=0$, because $P[Y_n=0]=0$ and $P[X_n=0]=2^{-n}\to 0.$)

Thus proceeding, with $s[1]$ denoting the first element of $s$, we have, for $0\lt k\lt n$:
$$\begin{align}B(n,k)
&\overset{1}{=}|\{s\in\{0,1\}^n:\ Y_n(s)=k\}|\\
&\overset{2}{=}2\ |\{s\in\{0,1\}^n:\ Y_n(s)=k,\ s[1]=0\}|\\
&\overset{3}{=}2\ |\{s\in\{0,1\}^{n-1}:\ X_{n-1}(s)=k\}\\
&\overset{4}{=}2\ A(n-1,k)
\end{align}$$

Eq.1 implies Eq.2 because there is a bijection between the sequences beginning with $0$ and those beginning with $1$, pairing each $s$ to its complement  $\bar s$ (i.e. with all bits complemented), such that  $Y_n(s)=Y_n(\bar s).$ (Any run in $s$ exactly matches a run of the complementary symbol in $\bar s.$ )

To show that Eq.2 implies Eq.3, denote the corresponding sets (suppressing $k$) as
$$T_n:=\{s\in\{0,1\}^n:\ Y_n(s)=k,\ s[1]=0\}\\[1ex] S_{n-1}:=\{s\in\{0,1\}^{n-1}:\ X_{n-1}(s)=k\}$$

Now, any element of $T_n$ can be written,  with unique positive integers $(n_1,...,n_j)$ summing to $n$, in the usual "run-length encoding" form
$$t =  \ 0^{n_1}1^{n_2}0^{n_3}1^{n_4}\dots b^{n_j}, \ \ b=(j+1)\bmod 2$$

and any element of $S_{n-1}$ can be written, with unique positive integers $(n_1,...,n_j)$ summing to $n$, in the special form
$$s =  \ 1^{n_1-1}01^{n_2-1}01^{n_3-1}\dots01^{n_j-1}$$

thus setting up the bijections

$$\underbrace{0^{n_1}1^{n_2}0^{n_3}1^{n_4}\dots b^{n_j}}_{\in T_n}\leftrightarrow(n_1,\dots,n_j)\leftrightarrow\underbrace{1^{n_1-1}01^{n_2-1}01^{n_3-1}\dots01^{n_j-1}}_{\in S_{n-1}}$$

Now,  $Y_n(0^{n_1}1^{n_2}0^{n_3}1^{n_4}\dots b^{n_j})=X_{n-1}(1^{n_1-1}01^{n_2-1}01^{n_3-1}\dots01^{n_j-1})=$ the multiplicity of $\max(n_1,...,n_j)$, the sole exception being when $n_1=\dots=n_j=1$ (which occurs iff $k=0$ or $k=n$; i.e. when $Y_n(0101...)=n\ne 0=X_{n-1}(000...)).$

Consequently, $|T_n| = |S_{n-1}|$ for $0\lt k\lt n$.
**QED**

Comment: To understand your definition, had you defined runs of 0's would the example have 2 runs of length 2? i.e., Do you allow overlaps or runs have to be delimited by the other symbol or be at the beginning or end of the sequence?

Comment: @kodlu It won't matter, since we're only looking at *longest* runs. In 110110001, the longest run of 0s is 000, whether or not overlap is allowed.

Comment: Your conjecture appears in "Brands, J. J. A. M., Steutel, F. W., & Wilms, R. J. G. (1994). On the number of maxima in a discrete sample. Statistics & Probability Letters, 20(3), 209–217. doi:10.1016/0167-7152(94)90044-2 " , formula 3.6

Comment: @leonbloy There is a non-paywalled [1992 Memorandum](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/2050509/380209.pdf) by the same authors, with the same title (but no "formula 3.6"). Would you mind checking whether these are substantially the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, rather a reference.

Let it be clear that we are considering the longest runs *of ones*  in $n$ fair coins.
Using [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409576/312), we can assume the runlengths correspond to iid geometric ($p=1/2$) variables. Because the mean of each one is $2$, we will have approximately near $n/2$ such variables, of which half are ones.

Then we can consider $t=n/4$ iid geometric variables $Y_j \in \{1,2 \cdots\}$ with $p=1/2$.

Letting $m=\max_{1 \le j \le t}(Y_j)$ be its maximum, we are interested in the distribution of the random variable $Z= \sum_{j}  [Y_j = m]$
as $t\to  \infty$.

(BTW: this formulation implies that, if the distribution exists, it does not matter if we consider the runs of ones, zeros, or both - and that the border effects are negligible).

This is quite a tough problem. The reference paper seems to be
*Brands, J. J. A. M.; Steutel, F. W.; Wilms, R. J. G.*, [**On the number of maxima in a discrete sample**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-7152(94)90044-2), Stat. Probab. Lett. 20, No. 3, 209-217 (1994). [ZBL0802.60048](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0802.60048). You already found a non-paywalled preprint from 1992 [here](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/2050509/380209.pdf).

There it's proved that, for our case, there is not a limit distribution of $Z$, there is an oscillation that does not fully vanish. But, numerically, the oscillation is small, so the distribution "almost" converges to a [logarithmic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_distribution):

$$ P(Z=k) \approx \frac{1}{k \, 2^k \log 2}$$

as you conjectured. This corresponds to formula $3.6$ in the original paper, $3.3$ in the 1992 preprint.

Comment: Very interesting! I'm still "digesting" the relevant  parts of the preprint, but because of the geometric r.v. heuristics,  it seems unclear that $Z_t$ and my $X_n$ necessarily have the same asymptotic behavior. E.g., the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A097979) entry for "the number of compositions of n+1 with unique largest part" (which could of course be wrong) states that $a(n)\sim 2^{n-1}/\log(2)$, implying $P[X_n=1]={a(n)\over 2^n}\to{1\over 2\log(2)}.$

Comment: Well, that agrees with $P(Z=1)$ (there was an error in my formula)

Comment: I'm referring to whether the limit exists or not. OEIS implies it does, under the usual meaning of "$\sim$". (BTW, I had posted a plot of $(P[X_n=1])_{n=10..100}$ [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4845482/16397) and mentioned the curious oscillations.)

Comment: Interesting. I cannot say. It would seem strange that going from the iid geometric setting to the fixed length $n$ original setting makes the oscillation disappear (asymptotically), but ...  I cannot say.

Comment: It seems clear that the reference paper does not strictly apply here. The reason is that it treats the multiplicity of $\max(N_1,\dots,N_n)$ where $n$ is *not* random, whereas my $X_n$ is the multiplicity of $\max(N_1,\dots,N_R)$, where $N_i$ is the length of the $i$th success run and  $R$ is the *random* number of success runs in $n$ Bernoulli trials.

Comment: Yes, but that should be asympotically equivalent. If we produce $t=n/2$ geometric rv with $p/2$, then sum $\sum Y_i$ will not be exactly $n$ but it concentrate around that value. This is a standard well known tool, see eg https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/07468342.di020742.02p0021g.pdf I concede that here the asymptotics are tricky, but I would doubt that this changes the result.

Comment: FWIW, to my [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4845482/16397) I've added a new plot of the $P[X_n=1]$ sequence, pushing $n$ up to $60000$. It is indeed consistent with the "almost convergence" described in the reference paper, agreeing with the oscillations having a limiting amplitude of $0.0000073...$ according to the paper.